# asp .net core-3.1 login using windows authentication with login page instead of browser popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am using .net core 3.1 for webapplication.

I have been trying to add login functionality which uses windows authentication on my .net core webapplication, I read some articles or stackoverflow threads,

those are suggesting to add following in launchSettings.json

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59164",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
```

this allow to open login popup on browser where user can put authentication to login  and access the application.

[image]

I want to have **login page instead of browser popup**, could someone please suggest/advise me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication is an auth mechanism which protects your resources before they are provided - this will include any home or login pages.

What you are looking for is a forms authentication method (in new .Net projects 'individual user accounts' would be closest) and then implement the lookup to your AD on a user submitting the login form.

In .Net full the easiest way was to use a `PrincipalContext` to a DC to check the user credentials but not sure if that's in .netstandard 2.1 (and thus core 3.1), if you use Azure AD then I'm sure there are different (more scalable) ways to achieve this too.

Other alternatives would be to use OAuth2 if you do use Azure AD.

**What I would recommend:** If this is a project that just needs authentication on all resources and all you're thinking about is to make it look pretty then - **don't.** Keep it simple - Auth is not an easy topic and can bog you down incredibly and add further scope creep. Windows Auth is not pretty but definitely works and as you see is incredibly easy to implement.

Hope this helps!